# typeahead bootstrap not working with dynamic data from php page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I want to use typeahead on input text, but it's not working.

my html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('asset/css/typeahead.css')?>">

<?php foreach ($driver as $d) { ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg typeahead" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="<?php echo $d['email']; }; ?>" id="email"  name="email">

<script src="<?php echo base_url('asset/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js') ?>"></script>
```

My controller :

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('user');
$query = $this->db->get();
$data['driver'] = $query->result_array();
```

When I start typing in input text, it shows nothing, it should be dropdown the `email` list provided from `select` query. No error return.

Comment: did you checked `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('asset/css/typeahead.css')?>">
` this line is correctly giving css file. May be your css files are not loading

Comment: i have checked it through `view page source` in browser and it's working fine @Anant

Comment: hope this will help you:- https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/creating-autocomplete-functionality-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: check and let us know

Comment: `remote: 'city.php?query=%QUERY'` i don't understand that part

Comment: they have given an example that how you need to format. you have to see the way and work accordingly. no need of copy and paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in your code. You are looping for each `$driver` and showing its email id in the data-source and the input tag is not closing.

For using bootstrap `typeaded`

1. Get list of all emails from `$driver` using following code 
   `$emails = array_column($driver, 'email');`
2. Create a string which will contain all the emails. All the emails should be wrapped in double quotes(`"`) and seperated by comma (`,`) 
   `$csv = "\"" . implode("\",\"", $emails) . "\"";`
3. Now create the typeahed input tag 
   `<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg typeahead" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='[<?php echo $csv; ?>]' id="email"  name="email">`
   Remember that the `data-source` attribute has single quote as start and end.